# Use 'ContactEmail' field of case in email template

Tags: email-template, case, case-object

I need to access value of contact email in email template using case object.'ContactEmail' is a standard case field is alredy availble, I am not able to see this field in case merge fileds.

Even if I write it manually, it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `{!Contact.Email}` as the merge field. Email templates on some standard objects (like Case) have implicit access to the  Contact lookup fields via `{Contact.xxx}` merge field syntax.

Here's an example of three ways to get at the Case's Contact Email and the corresponding rendered results:

```
Case.ContactEmail: {!Case.ContactEmail}

Case.Contact.Email: {!Case.Contact} // you can't even save the expression {!Case.Contact.Email}, 
                                       save coerces it to {!Case.Contact}

Contact.Email : {!Contact.Email}
```

results:

```
Case.ContactEmail:  // nothing!

Case.Contact.Email: Foo Bar // returns Contact's Name!

Contact.Email : foo.bar@fubar.com  // email as desired
```

Comment: The Email gets trigger on creation of case, so I need to refer the case object in email template. Need to use contact email by using case object only.

Comment: @Shilpa my point is that email template where Case is the target object can still use Contact merge fields as behind the scenes, SFDC binds to both the Case standard controller AND the Contact standard controller

Comment: It is  HTML email template not the VF template.